# kali linux not asking password to login ( in persistence using USB)

Tags: linux, usb, passwords, kali-linux, persistence

Iam using kali using persistence usb.

1. Everytime I open my system using kali persistence , it doesn't ask for password for the **first time** (i.e **gives access to the root user without any authentication**), but it does asks for password when i lock the screen.
2. I have to change root password every single session I use kali. **i.e. it always sets its password to default one (toor) for next session.** So, next time when i use kali, my password is not what I chose, instead , its "toor" again.

Above things continues.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

1. Edit `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` with your editor of choice and comment (disable) following lines:

   ```
   AutomaticLoginEnable = true
   AutomaticLogin = root
   TimedLoginEnable = true
   TimedLogin = root
   TimedLoginDelay = 5
   ```
2. Run passwd and change root password, then run `cat /etc/shadow | grep root | awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`  and the new hash will be shown, after that edit `/lib/live/config/0031-root-password` and swap the old hash (for toor password) with the one you obtained with last command.